# Highcharts - Categories and X,Y data

Tags: highcharts

Whenever I set the categories for X, Y data in highcharts it shifts the categories so that the first one appears on the zero. For example, if I have x and y data that go from one to ten as in [[1,1],[2,2],... then the categories only show up on the 1 through 9 numbers and are shifted by one as if the first item appears on the zero category.

Is there any way to address this?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfoxworth/3hGtL/)

I am using the command :

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']);
```

Comment: Simple add `null` as first element.

Comment: I can do that for the example, but I am trying to make a site that is user friendly and it could have an X axis starting at a very high value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming Highcharts will start from 1, while they start from 0. If you will remove all x-values from data, you will see that are starting from 0. Unfortunately this is part of Highcharts logic (based on Javascript arrays) and won't be changed.

And just in case - don't try to use logarithmic axis with categories.. ;)

Comment: To expand on this answer: the solution, therefore, is to adjust the x values in your data accordingly.  Using your example of month names for categories, you simply need to refer to January data as x value 0, and so on.

Comment: Or just add one, fake cateogory on the beggining of array. Sorry forget to place full answer. With setting xAxis.min = 1 (like in answer by Pierre) with do a full work.